# Simple ordering for a linked list

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, language-agnostic

I want to  create a doubly linked list with an order sequence (an integer attribute) such that sorting by the order sequence could create an array that would effectively be equivalent to the linked list.

```
given: a <-> b <-> c

a.index > b.index 
b.index > c.index
```

This index would need to handle efficiently arbitrary numbers of inserts.

**Is there a known algorithm for accomplishing this?**
The problem is when the list gets large and the index sequence has become packed. In that situation the list has to be scanned to put slack back in.
I'm just not sure how this should be accomplished. Ideally there would be some sort of automatic balancing so that this borrowing is both fast and rare.

The naive solution of changing all the left or right indecies by 1 to make room for the insert is O(n).

I'd prefer to use integers, as I know numbers tend to get less reliable in floating point as they approach zero in most implementations.

Comment: Why oh why dlinked lists? Why not [balanced trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree#Implementations)? No problem with growing/skrinking, O(log(N)) operations.

Comment: "The naive solution of changing all the left or right indecies by 1 to make room for the insert is O(n)." If you really insist on a "dlinked *paged* solution" (for whatever reason), instead of distributing a slack to all pages, you can simply split a page in which you want to insert but the page reached its fill-factor.

Comment: How are new items inserted into the doubly linked list? Are they inserted at the head or the tail? Or an arbitrary location in the middle? Note that inserting an item into the middle of the doubly linked list takes O(n), unless you are maintaining pointers to the individual items, in which case maintaining those extra pointers would take time.

Comment: Strangely similar to the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280301/linked-list-with-fast-node-order-querying?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of my favorite problems.  In the literature, it's called "online list labeling", or just "list labeling".  There's a bit on it in wikipedia here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-maintenance_problem#List-labeling

Probably the simplest algorithm that will be practical for your purposes is the first one in here: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sleator/papers/maintaining-order.pdf.

It handles insertions in amortized O(log N) time, and to manage N items, you have to use integers that are big enough to hold N^2.  64-bit integers are sufficient in almost all practical cases.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this looks really cool. It shouldn't be too hard to impliment.

Comment: Just want to tack on for all the .net developers the nuget package manager command for getting this algorithm is : Install-Package C5

Answer (score 0):

What I wound up going for was a roll-my-own solution, because it looked like the algorithm wanted to have the entire list in memory before it would insert the next node. And that is no good.

My idea is to borrow some of the ideas for the algorithm. What I did was make Ids ints and sort orders longs. Then the algorithm is lazy, stuffing entries anywhere they'll fit. Once it runs out of space in some little clump somewhere it begins a scan up and down from the clump and tries to establish an even spacing such that if there are n items scanned they need to share n^2 padding between them.

In theory this will mean over time the list will be perfectly padded, and given that my IDs are ints and my sort orders are longs, there will never be a scenario where you will not be able to achieve n^2 padding.  I can't speak to the upper bounds on the number of operations, but my guts tell me that by doing polynomial work at 1/polynomial frequency, that I'll be doing just fine.